# SwiftUI ForEach's onMove() modifier stop working if the content view has tap gesture action

Tags: macos, swiftui, touch, gesture

I want to make a list view which contents could be dragged for reordering and tapped for detail.
But when I add the onTapGesture() action in the content view, the onMove() action stop working.

Example code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestTapAndMove: View {
    @State private var users = ["Paul", "Taylor", "Adele"]

    var body: some View {
            List {
                ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user in
                    VStack {
                        Text("user: \(user)").font(.headline)
                        
                        Divider()
                    }.background(Color.gray)

                    // The TapGesture will result in onMove action not working.
                    .onTapGesture(perform: {
                        print("tap!")
                    })
                }
                .onMove(perform: move)
            }
    }

    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        print("onMove!")
        users.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
}
```

Is there any solution that could make the tap and move action work together?

Comment: @Asperi, There is no edit mode in my case. It's just one list view showing content titles without any "edit" or "reorder" button. And if I clicked the content title, the App could switch to the detail view. I recorded a gif to show a similar case: https://ibb.co/fHH6cX0

Comment: I missed [macos]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As workaround you can make some specific part of row clickable, like text in below example (or some added custom shape or plain button)

```
VStack {
    Text("user: \(user)").font(.headline)
      .onTapGesture(perform: {
            print("tap!")
      })
    Divider()
}.background(Color.gray)
```

**Alternate:** you can add helper custom view as row overlay which would handle tap/mouseDown action for view (and does not break drug)

```
class TapHandlerView: NSView {
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseDown(with: event)   // keep this to allow drug !!
        print("tap")
    }
}

struct TapHandler: NSViewRepresentable {
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> TapHandlerView {
        TapHandlerView()
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: TapHandlerView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

and use it

```
VStack {
    Text("user: \(user)").font(.headline)
    Divider()
}.background(Color.gray)
.overlay(TapHandler())         // << here !!
```

Tested with Xcode 12.0 / macOS 10.15.6

Comment:   The alternate solution TapHandler is better. Thanks, Asperi.

Comment: In a list, trying to make my content (text) use .onTap just led to the compiler not being able to cope. As a workaround, I've wrapped my list content in a VStack. Now I get the tap gesture when I click on the Text, and I can move my rows when I click anywhere else.

Comment: I found similar and more generic solution here where the action can also be passed as a parameter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75814261/3013992