# Error with initializers and super.init() in NSView Class

Tags: swiftui, nsview

I'm quite a newbie at SwitUI development and I've been almost a week trying to solve a problem but i'm really frustrated about.

The thing is very simple I guess. I just trying to send a `@Binding` var to a `NSView` class and print the value in my console on click in a SwiftUI View.

Code

**This is my code:**

```
import SwiftUI

class TapHandlerView: NSView {
   
  @Binding var text: String
   
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
   
  init(text: Binding<String>) {
    self._text = text
    super.init(text: text) // Line error -> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments
  }

  override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    super.mouseDown(with: event) 
    print(text)
  }
}

struct TapHandler: NSViewRepresentable {
   
  @Binding var text: String

  func makeNSView(context: Context) -> TapHandlerView {
    TapHandlerView(text: $text)
  }

  func updateNSView(_ nsView: TapHandlerView, context: Context) {
  }
}

struct ItemView: View {

  @State var text: String = "Hello!"

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Click here!")
    }
    .overlay(TapHandler(text: $text))
  }
}
```

_

**This is the error I get:**

```
super.init(text: text)
```

```
Argument passed to call that takes no arguments
```

_

For more context, I come from here:
[SwiftUI ForEach's onMove() modifier stop working if the content view has tap gesture action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64194207/swiftui-foreachs-onmove-modifier-stop-working-if-the-content-view-has-tap-ges)

I hope that someone can help me and sorry if is a silly question, I feel like I'm missing something very basic but im blocked with it.

Thank you!

Comment: What does 'init(text: Binding<String>) {}' mean?

Comment: SwiftUI wrappers such as `@Binding` do not work in a `class` they only work in a `struct` that is a `View`. The only exception in `@Published` in an `ObservableObject`.